# Automatically add another type form when one is filled

Tags: html, forms, input

When the user enters some (any) text on the type form, I would like for a second form to show up and same for the second one etc.
Is there a way to do this without create multiple hidden forms and just show them with jQuery when something is typed? because I would have to have more than ten forms in html...

Thanks for the help! I will insert an example of a single form for you to work on

```html
<div class="command">

  <form method="post" action="traitement.php">
    <label for="article">Articles:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="article" placeholder="Ex: T-shirt, XL" id="article">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: So when the first form is filled, an other one shows up ? Do you want to have a text limit or a button that will add the other form ?

Comment: No text limit, and no button either unless it's necessary! Just another form automatically appearing under @LPK

Comment: Ok, so automatically add one form when the user click or enter text in one ?@Maëlle Jumel

Comment: Yes exactly @LPK

Answer (score 2):

I know that's not really what you're looking for, but it may help you in an other way. You specify the number you want in the first form then click the link, and it generate the number of forms previously entered.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addFields(){
        // Number of inputs to create
        var number = document.getElementById("article").value;
        // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        // Clear previous contents of the container
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            // Append a node with a random text
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Article" + (i+1)));
            // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "article" + i;
            container.appendChild(input);
            // Append a line break 
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="article" name="article" placeholder="Ex: T-shirt, XL" value="">Number of Article (enter a number)<br />
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Click Me</a>
<div id="container"/>
```

**EDIT**

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addFields(){
        for (i=0;i<1;i++){
            // Append a node with a random text
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Article"));
            // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "article";
            container.appendChild(input);
            // Append a line break 
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="article" onclick="addFields()" name="article" placeholder="Ex: T-shirt, XL" value="">Number of Article (click to add an article)<br />
  
<div id="container"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! It might not be what I want exactly but it rly helps!

Comment: I'll look forward to really fit your need !

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#article").keyup(function(){
                    $('body').append('<form method="post" action="traitement.php" id="secondForm"></form>');
                    $('#secondForm').append('<input type="text" id="secondArticle" name="secondArticle">');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="command">
            <form method="post" action="traitement.php">
                <label for="article">Articles:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="article" placeholder="Ex: T-shirt, XL" id="article">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to create the new form when we type anything in the existing form. So, we can able to use a KeyUp function in jquery. After typed anything in a text box, the new form and input textbox will be created.

This is just a simple example. Hope, this will help.

**EDIT:**

```
$("#article").keyup(function(){
    if($('#secondForm').length == 0){
        $('body').append('<form method="post" action="traitement.php" id="secondForm"></form>');
        $('#secondForm').append('<input type="text" id="secondArticle" name="secondArticle">');
    }
});
```

Comment: That is actually very close to what I want, there are two problems though: forms keep popping up whenever something is typed in the first form even though only one should and also I would like for that to work on the second form too and the third etc. But with variables maybe I can get this to work so thanks a lot for this example!

Comment: So, Need to create a second form for first typing only? If I type the second letter in the first form, we need to skip the form creation. Right?

Comment: Yes (I changed keyup function to input and it fixed this problem). The second thing is now just to replace ids with variables so it can work on all the further forms.

Comment: Please see our EDIT code part. I have added a code to form creation for second typing.